# Howto get Firebase onCall and async response in it's most basic form: {"error":{"message":"Bad Request","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}

Tags: firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to test *CLoud Functions* in a basic way to get started with *Firebase*. Yes, I've read about `onCall`, `onRequest`, `async` and about `Promise` but still, I haven't been able to run a simple test. Please, enlighten me in the right direction...

I'm trying this simple test:

***functions/index.js***

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onCall(examples.helloWorld);
```

***functions/examples.js***

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.helloWorld = async  (data, context) =>{
        return Promise.resolve();
    };
```

I'm just trying to get a response using *Postman* or the web browser, but I get the following response:

```
{"error":{"message":"Bad Request","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}
```

How can I achieve this in the most simple way? What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand what you want to do, I replaced the code in examples.js for

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.helloWorld = async (req, res) => {
  // Send back a message that we've succesfully written the message
  res.json({result: `Message sent.`});

};
```

And the code executes properly.